# What mysql data type should I use for encrypted text?

Tags: mysql, encryption

Here's the type of text my encryption function throws out: [image: encrypted text]

I generated several strings and they're never bigger than 50 characters, but I would like to give it 75 characters in mysql. I tried using varchar, but the string gets cut off because it doesn't like some characters. Any idea what data type I should use?

Comment: Probably need to alter the [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) and not the data type.

Comment: I'm using utf8_unicode_ci and recommendations? there's like 50 of them o_0

Comment: What character encoding is your code generating?

Comment: I'm using rijndael-256 and cfb mode in mcrypt. Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's binary data (it looks like it is), you probably should store it in a `BLOB`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `blob`, but for short data, that will make your selects slow.
Use `binary(75)` or `varbinary(75)`.